# Find artifactory URL from another Jenkins build

Tags: java, jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have a Jenkins job that build and upload an .ear to Artifactory. I'm creating another Jenkins job that will deploy this application on a few servers using ansible. How can I make it find the most recent build and get the artifactory URL for the ear file that was built?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jenkins you can use the process of upstream -> downstream or pipeline based process for the deployment of the .ear files.

Artifactory url consists of two parts one fixed and another variable.

For e.g.

fixed --> https://artifact.domain.com:8081/artifactory
variable -- repo_name
https://artifact.domain.com:8081/artifactory/$repo_name/

For getting the lastest build number you can also use the artifactory api key value RELEASED

[Artifactory REST Api](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API)

You can also use jenkins plugin of artifactory for dependencies download to download the .ear file if the app is simple